# Prove if the function is coercive

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

Thank you for the comments and answers!

> Show if the function is coercive: 
>   $$f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2 - xy - x$$

Have some difficulties dealing with the last $x$ term, tried to replace it with $|xy|$, didn't work. Could someone give me some hints of how to approach such question.

Note: definition of coercive, $$f(z)\rightarrow +\infty, as \  \|z\|\to\infty $$

Comment: Complete squares. First in $y$ then in $x$.

Comment: ignore the $x$ to start. What is the minimum of $x^2 - xy + y^2$ on the unit circle $x^2 + y^2 = 1?$

Comment: @user251257  It's $f(x)$ goes to positive infinity, have checked with my lecture notes, it is the right definition.

Comment: To avoid confusions, say $f(z)\rightarrow +\infty$ as $ \|z\|\to\infty$.

Comment: @WillJagy Sorry, I didn't quite follow it here. Why would we calculate a minimum?

Comment: @A.G. Thanks! I've changed it.

Comment: @A.G. Thank you for the hint! I got it.

Comment: here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1960532/prove-a-quadratic-function-is-coercive-iff-the-hessian-is-positive-definite you gave a general method to show if a cuadratic function is coercive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $f(z)=z^THz+c^Tz$ with invertible $H$ can be written as
$$
f(z)=(z+\frac12H^{-1}c)^TH(\underbrace{z+\frac12H^{-1}c}_{\hat z})-\frac14c^TH^{-1}c=g(\hat z).
$$
Now $f$ is coercive iff $g$ is coercive.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a purposely less refined answer.

You have a part $x^2 + y^2$ which looks coercive and a part $-xy - x$ which does not.

Let's borrow some of the coercive part to compensate $x y$ first:
$$
|xy| \leq \tfrac12 (x^2 + y^2)
,
$$
so that 
$$
f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2 - xy - x \geq
\tfrac12 (x^2 + y^2) - x
.
$$

The only way this could fail to be coercive is when $-x$ is very small; but then $\tfrac12 x^2$ is much larger than $|x|$, compensating again.

Answer (score 0):

Using polar coordinates:
$$
f(r,\theta)=r^2-r^2\cos\theta\sin\theta-r\cos\theta=r^2(1-\cos\theta\sin\theta)-r\cos\theta
$$
In the direction $\theta=\pi/2$:
$$
f(r,\pi/2)=r^2\rightarrow \infty\quad \mbox{when}\; r\rightarrow \infty
$$