# Prove a quadratic function is coercive iff the Hessian is positive definite?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization

Given a quadratic function in $x$, $f(x)=\frac{1}2x^TAx-b^Tx$. Prove $f(x)$ is coercive if and only if A is positive definite matrix.

A function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is called coercive if $f(x) \rightarrow + \infty \; \text{as} \; |x| \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2166509/is-this-function-coercive

Comment: Complete solution https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.siam.org/books/mo19/MO19_ch2.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjemJuq7ZHbAhVECuwKHZWxDHEQFjADegQIAxAB&usg=AOvVaw3dOSXeY6sP085VfBQHSbQJ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $A$ is positive definite then the eigenvalues of $A$ are all positive. In particular, the smallest eigenvalue, say $\lambda_s$, will be nonzero. Next observe
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2}x^TAx-b^Tx=\frac{1}{2}x^TQ^TDQx-b^Tx=\geq\frac{\lambda_s}{2}\| Qx\|^2-\|b\|\|x\|=\frac{\lambda_s}{2}\|x\|^2-\|b\|\|x\|.
\end{align}
Thus as $\|x\|\rightarrow \infty$ we see that $f$ will also go to infinity.

For the converse direction, assume $A$ is not positive definite then there is an eigen-direction corresponding to a non-positive eigenvalue, say $x$. Then we see that if $\lambda<0$ then
\begin{align} 
f(\alpha x)= \frac{\lambda\alpha^2}{2}\|x\|^2-\alpha b^Tx\leq \frac{\lambda\alpha^2}{2}\|x\|^2+|\alpha|\|b\|\| x\|
\end{align}
which goes to negative infinity as $|\alpha|\rightarrow \infty$. For the case $\lambda=0$, we will leave it as an exercise for the reader.